# Compare string to text from clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to cross check a column is available in a required order.

In the clipboard the variable is "User Name" exactly same.

But the msgbox does not pop up with the message.

```vb
Sub macro1()
    Dim Mystring As String
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    Mystring = DataObj.GetText
    If Mystring = "User Name" Then
        MsgBox "Correct column"
    End If
End Sub
```

My requirement is:
Check a Excel file report and arrange that data in a particular order.

For example:
If columns are in A,B,C,D,E,F,G order I want to change the order into C,A,B,G,E,F,D with below data as well.

Comment: May I know why do you try using a `DataObject` for such a simple task? Do you want playing with this object? Otherwise, using Clipboard only consumes Excel resources and makes the code slower, without bringing any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The data object is adding additional characters to the end of the string.

Open your immediate window (ctrl + g on the IDE window) and you can test that here:

```
Sub macro1()
 
Dim Mystring As String
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    Mystring = DataObj.GetText
        If Trim(Mystring) = "User Name" Then
            MsgBox "Correct column"
        End If
    
    
    'Comparing strings
    Dim i As Long
    Debug.Print Len(Mystring), Len("User Name")
    For i = 1 To Len(Mystring)
        Debug.Print Mid(Mystring, i, 1), Asc(Mid(Mystring, i, 1))
    Next i
    
    
 End Sub
```

If you run that code you can see that the string derived from the data object has an extra line break and carriage return, ascii codes 10 and 13 respectively.

The easiest way to avoid this is to skip the entire clipboard / data object and just pull the string directly from the range.

```
Sub NewMacro1()
    Dim mystring As String
    
    mystring = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
        
    If mystring = "User Name" Then
        MsgBox "Correct Column"
    End If
End Sub
```